# Resolving Dependencies in Gradle

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I have a doubt regarding adding dependencies to Gradle . If my project is dependent on a jar file, which in turn has a number of transitive dependencies , will all the jars including the transitive dependencies be placed in Clas path . And if a particular jar is a first level dependency and it is also a transitive dependent jar for another first level dependent Jar, how to handle this

Comment: 1. it depends on the dependency scope (i.e. compile, runtime, test, etc.) 2. there's nothing to handle: the jar is required twice instead of once, so what? Have you read the manual, which covers these topics in great length? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

Comment: Yeah I have read that ,still I couldn't understand : 1) Sice the first level dependency jar is available as transitive dependency for another jar, it would also be available in class path. So, I removed  the first level dependency jar . but it throwed error :(

Comment: If you have a question about code, post the code. Don't describe it. As I said, it all depends on the **scope** of the transitive dependency. But posting a minimal gradle build file and class reproducing the problem would allow explaining exactly what happens.